# How to fill meta tag from code behind in server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags, meta

im trying fill meta tag from code behind.

Trial-1

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
tag.Name = "description";
tag.Content = "My description for this page";
Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

Trial -2

```
Page.Title = "lorem ipsum";
Page.MetaDescription = "loremmmmmm";
```

This solution was work in localhost. I publish my server but it's not working.
any ideas?

Comment: does your head tag in your html have runat="server" in it?

Comment: yes i have.. <head runat="server">

Comment: Cool, are you putting it in a master page or regular page?

Comment: regular page.. http://www.afillikutu.com/Bloglar/Neden-Kitap-Bu-Kadar-Onemli/2

Comment: Next step would be to debug it, can you hit a breakpoint on your code?

Comment: no problem in localhost..

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

In the head of your master:

```
<%# _metaA %>
<%# _metaB %>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string _metaA;
    public string _metaB;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ex:
        _metaA = "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"Content\" />";
        _metaB = "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"Content\" />";
        Page.Header.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: this way is working localhost.. and publish in server error..  Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name '_metaA' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sry, fixed an error in **public strings**. make sure all the `meta` names match.